# aws lambda cannot make a http call

Tags: lambda

I'm trying to make a simple http request from a lambda function.  But for some reason any request does not seem to go through.  Does the lambda environment block any request.  The lambda is on a No VPC configuration.

I did a bit of research on this and found the following

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=731223

But this is really beyond my comprehension on subnets.  But from what I understand here if its not on any VPC it should make the call successfully?

Comment: Lambda without vpc should allow to make http request, what error are you seeing in Lambda execution?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda doesn't block any network requests but since the ENI attached to the Lambda doesn't have a public IP address any public REST API call will fail.

The solution to that is to route the traffic to a NAT Gateway/instance from the subnet the Lambda is in. That NAT would then reside in a subnet that has a default route to an internet gateway.

If the Lambda function's code does not need to access a private resource in the VPC you should remove it. Having a Lambda in a VPC only complicates executions by increasing cold start time and ensuring there's enough IPs in the subnets for the ENIs to assume. Here is a doc about Lambda in a VPC.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html#lambda-vpc

Hth

-James